# react-virtualized dynamically updating Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, callback, react-virtualized

I have modified the simple example in `react-virtualized Grid` as follows. While this code works, I have a two part question:

1. how do I modify the example so that on a `timer` `callback`, `quoteChange` will be
   called with random values.
2. If I modify the `quoteList`, will the `Grid` automatically update without calling `cellRenderer` ?

The code. The idea is to have an application that looks like it is displaying **streaming real-time quotes**. Note that `quoteChange` currently doesn't do anything. It is my feeble attempt at a first try.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Grid } from 'react-virtualized';

// Grid data as an array of arrays
const quoteList = [
  ['GE', 100, 35.28, 35.30, 100, 95125],
  ['IBM', 100, 135.11, 135.20, 100, 195125],
  ['C', 100, 45.23, 45.30, 100, 195125]
];

function quoteChange(ri, bid, ask)
{
    quoteList[ri][2] = bid
    quoteList[ri][3] = ask

    var bi = {
        columnIndex : 2,
        rowIndex : ri,
    }

    cellRenderer(bi)

    var ba = {
        columnIndex : 3,
        rowIndex : ri,
    }

    cellRenderer(ba)
}

function cellRenderer ({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style }) {
  return (
    <div
      key={key}
      style={style}
    >
      {quoteList[rowIndex][columnIndex]}
    </div>
  )  
}

// Render your grid
ReactDOM.render(
  <Grid
    cellRenderer={cellRenderer}
    columnCount={quoteList[0].length}
    columnWidth={50}
    height={quoteList.length * 20}
    rowCount={quoteList.length}
    rowHeight={20}
    width={800}
  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 4):

> If I modify the quoteList, will the Grid automatically update without calling cellRenderer ?

No. This is mentioned [at the beginning of the docs](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized#pure-components). ;)

> ## Pure Components
>
> By default all react-virtualized components use shallowCompare to avoid re-rendering unless props or state has changed. This ocassionally confuses users when a collection's data changes (eg `['a','b','c']` => `['d','e','f']`) but props do not (eg `array.length`).
>
> The solution to this is to let react-virtualized know that something external has changed. This can be done a couple of different ways.
>
> ### Pass-thru props
>
> The `shallowCompare` method will detect changes to any props, even if they aren't declared as `propTypes`. This means you can also pass through additional properties that affect cell rendering to ensure changes are detected. For example, if you're using `List` to render a list of items that may be re-sorted after initial render- react-virtualized would not normally detect the sort operation because none of the properties it deals with change. However you can pass through the additional sort property to trigger a re-render. For example:

```
<List
  {...listProps}
  sortBy={sortBy}
/>
```

> ### Public methods
>
> `Grid` and `Collection` components can be forcefully re-rendered using `forceUpdate`. For `Table` and `List`, you'll need to call `forceUpdateGrid` to ensure that the inner `Grid` is also updated.

Comment: Thanks. So in the Grid example, what do I pass to Grid to make it redraw on a quoteList item change (not an operation on the entire list of list, just a lsingle list item change)? I am assuming that forceUpdate is expensive since it probably redraws the entire grid.

Comment: My solution: i've defined a state of the component with the same data passed to the grid, than i defined `{...listProps}` into che Grid component like the example tells.
Than, with `componentWillReceiveProps()` i'll update the state with the new data. This cause the re-render of the component when the data changes. Hope this helps.

Comment: In the Table example, where should I call `forceUpdateGrid()`? In the `render()` function of my self-defined react component which wraps the `<Table />`? Thanks!

Comment: `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()` is marked as "unsafe" now. What should we use instead?

Comment: @YixingLiu This blog post goes into detail about that: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html